# Why is my message undefined when i execute my bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

hi everyone :) absolute newbie here and im trying to make some fun little commands  for my discord bot. its throwing up a message not defined error and im at the end of my rope. im sure this is a simple tying i should be able to comprehend but unfortunately im dumb hah. any help is greatly appreciated! heres the  code if it helps -

```
 case 'shell' :
            const personTagged = message.mentions.members.first();

            if(!args[1]) {
                message.channel.send('you aint writing it right sTOOPID!')
            }else{
                message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' has shelled ' + personTagged.displayName + ' ' + doshellAction())
            }

            break;
```

Comment: Where is this code? Could you please show where `message` is defined/where it is a function parameter?

Answer (score 0):

The example code on the [discord.js homepage](https://discord.js.org/#/) is:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

You will need some code like this for your bot to authenticate with Discord and listen for messages. A simplified version of your code implemented inside this sample code looks like this:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', message => { // This is where message comes from!
  // message will be defined in this code block
  let personTagged = message.mentions.members.first();
  message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' has shelled ' + personTagged.displayName + ' ' + doshellAction());
});

client.login('token');
```